# Get Internet usage from fortigate using php

Tags: php, charts, freeradius

I working on WIFI management system using PHP , fortigate firewall and freeradius server. every thing go fine but now I want to display real time internet usage by users  in my system interface , users will access internet through fortigate so fortigate can log every things about that users, how can I access  real time internet usage chart into  fortigate from my system and display that chart into my system's interface , or get the value of internet usage every second .

Please help me .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you very much. I trying to get the values using freeradius but freeradius store internet usage of every user when that user is being disconnected so I can not access to the real value till the user is disconnect , suppose that every user will connect for 2 days for example that mean I will not access the user's internet usage for 2 dayes